# white or light ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton "Sign in with Apple" button - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am implementing ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton - as per Apple's request - but unfortunately my login background is dark and I can't find how to change the button color to a light or white button like the ones Apple show in many of their examples?

This is what I have:

```
let appleButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()       
    setAppleButtonStyle()
}

func setAppleButtonStyle() {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        appleButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(appleButton)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            appleButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: facebookLoginView.centerYAnchor, constant: -70),
            appleButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            appleButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            appleButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        ])
    } else {
        //Do Nothing
    }

}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply provide the desired [`style`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationappleidbutton/style) when you instantiate the button instance.

E.g.

```
let appleButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .default, style: .white)
```

Comment: is there any way to dynamically change the style when the user switches dark mode on or off? I didn't find a separate setter for `style`.

Answer (score 4):

This would be what you would use if you were using Objective-C:

```
 ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton *appleIDButton = [ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton buttonWithType:ASAuthorizationAppleIDButtonTypeContinue style:ASAuthorizationAppleIDButtonStyleBlack];
```

Comment: But the question asked for an answer in swift. Can you provide the swift version of your answer?

Comment: I was looking for an answer in objective c and i found this answer which is an alternate. Above answer in swift is correct. I was trying to add alternate code in objective c

Answer (score 1):

Dark Mode supportable auto style:

```
let button: ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton = ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(
    authorizationButtonType: .default,
    authorizationButtonStyle: UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? .white : .black
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.0 with SwiftUI, automatically adjusts to dark mode

```
import SwiftUI
import AuthenticationServices

final class AppleSignInButton: UIViewRepresentable {
  @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
  
  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton {
    return ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton(type: .default, style: colorScheme == .dark ? .white : .black)
  }
  func updateUIView(_ uiView: ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton, context: Context) {
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
AppleSignInButton()
  .frame(width: 300, height: 56) // You can change these values
  .onTapGesture {
    // Do log in stuff
  }
```